# SAML Signature Tag Name Standard

Tags: c#, single-sign-on, saml, saml-2.0

Shouldn't the SAML Signature be always `<ds:Signature ></ds:Signature>`...  I have noticed some Idp use `<Signature>` and some use `<ds:Signature>`

In C# I am trying to get the Signature node using.

```
XmlNodeList nodeList = samlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("ds:Signature");
```

It fails when the Signature tag starts with `<Signature>` without `ds:` prefix. Is there anything that I am missing here?

Comment: You need to deal with the `ds:` namespace. Not familiar with C#, but this looks like where you should start: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/managing-namespaces-in-an-xml-document

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. There is no requirement to use ds as the prefix. There are certain conventions followed with most Java implementations using the ds prefix but the .NET framework doesn't. Someone could use xyz as the prefix if they chose to do so.

What's important is the element name (Signature) and the namespace under which it's declared (http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#). You should make no assumptions about the prefix. Select the node based off element name and namespace and ignore the prefix completely.

Answer (score 1):

No, it shouldn't be there in case it is mentioned it in the namespace above the element, like this:

```
<samlp:Response xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" 
    xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" 
    ...>
    <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        ...
    </Signature>
</samlp:Response>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Andrew, ComponentSpace, and Yarkov for the answers highlighting the importance of namespace. I have used the `XmlNamespaceManager` from `System.XML` Assembly to get the Signature value.

```
XmlNamespaceManager manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(samlDoc.NameTable);
manager.AddNamespace("ds", SignedXml.XmlDsigNamespaceUrl);
manager.AddNamespace("saml", "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion");
manager.AddNamespace("samlp", "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol");
XmlNodeList nodeList = samlDoc.SelectNodes("//ds:Signature", manager);
```